# json loop access via dynamic property

Tags: json, loops, dynamic-properties

```
var opt = $.extend({
        jsonOptions :{
                value   : 'id',
                text    : 'text',
            },
    }, options );

return elem.bind("keyup.myPlugin", function () {
$.ajax({
            url:'abc.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{title:$(this).val()},

            success:function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(obj.length){
                    var ul = '<ul>';
                    $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
//here I want to access item.DYNAMIC_PROPERTY
//item.(opt.jsonOptions.value) gives error

                        ul += ' <li data-id="'+item.(opt.jsonOptions.value)+'">';
                        ul += item.(opt.jsonOptions.text);
                        ul += ' </li>';
                    });
                    ul += ' </ul>';
                    drp.html(ul);   
                }else{
                    drp.html('<div style="text-align:center;">No match found.</span>');
                }
            }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

worked for me as below

```
item[opt.jsonOptions.value]
```